# how to click close button in onbeforeunload pop up using javascript or angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application need to do the onbeforeunload pop up click close button pragmatically using java script or angular.. please help me it will help me lot..

I have tried like this but its closed the tab without displaying leaving message.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  return; 
}
```

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = function () {return "sure?" }` works?

Comment: yeah its works but i need to trigger stay this page button using javascript

Comment: I don't get it. You want to make user unable to close the page? This is impossible and will never be possible and you should feel guilty.